# displaying images stored in database as a gallery

Tags: java, mysql, database, grid, gallery

I'm working on a project which displays images stored in mysql database as a grid or gallery. We have stored the images in mysql database as BLOB data and succeeded in retrieving image and displaying it in a new frame as:

```
if (rs.next())
            {
                byte[] imagedata = rs.getBytes("image_path") ;
                Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imagedata);
                 JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);  
                frame.setTitle("THE PICTURE RETRIEVED");                           
                ImageIcon icon =new ImageIcon(img);
                JLabel Photo = new JLabel(icon) ;   

                //setLayout(null);                 
                frame.add(Photo) ;  
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null)));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true); }
```

Now I'd like to display the images stored in database as a grid of images in a new window or as a gallery.

How can I do that? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: So, since you can already display the images in a new frame, does this question have anything to do with mysql or the database?

Comment: @cdeszaq : i juz wanted to know is there any way to display the entire images stored in database at once like a gallery...can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a web application it is really easily done using Datagrid component of Richfaces or PrimeFaces.

Why don't you use JPA?

Here is a quick tutorial how to do it in a web app:
http://tutslink.blogspot.com/2012/04/jsf-displaying-images-from-database-in.html